# Multisite Subdomain 404 errors

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I am a beginner in wordpress.I was in need to setup multisite, i managed to setup everything as mentioned in the codex. I created a subdomain, it appears on the dashboard under site, but when i click on it it shows 404 page not found error. Dns wild card is set, the wp config file and .htacess(i copied the network setup in to it).Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

my .ht access file=>

'   # Use PHP 5.3
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php53/lib
    # BEGIN WordPress
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

```
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>'

# END WordPress

wp_config file=>
'define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '***.net');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */'

Reply
```

Answer (score 0):

i was using an addon domain, so the wildcard setting was different.I tried setting it in this way http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/wildcard-dns-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it after few hours everything worked fine.